# dijit.form.TextBox Add strings on click of a buton based on the last selection

Tags: internet-explorer, textbox, dojo, cursor-position, dijit.form

How to retain cursor position even after loosing focus in dijit.form.TextBox?
I have the textbox and button in my form. When I click on the button I want some text to be added in that textbox at specific cursor position which I have retained.

I want something exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NE4Ev/6/
but this does not work in Internet Explorer.
Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 2):

Listen to TextBox's `onblur` event to save cursor position:

```
textBox.on("blur", function() {
    var start = this.textbox.selectionStart,
        end = this.textbox.selectionEnd;
    this.set("cursorPosition", [start, end]);
});
```

You can use that position to insert some text at cursor position and also restore cursor position, when returning focus to textbox programmatically by calling `textBox.focus()`, e.g. when user clicks a button:

```
textBox.on("focus", function() {
    var cursorPosition = this.get("cursorPosition");
    if(cursorPosition) {            
        this.textbox.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition[0], cursorPosition[1]);                                          
    }
});
```

See working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/rryEg/

Comment: In that working example text i.e. "foo" gets added at the end but I want it to be added at the retained cursor position.
Suppose initially the text in textbox is "some text here" and cursor is at x in "text" then after clicking on button the text in textbox should be "some **tefooxt** here".

Comment: Worked as per modifications stated by MozenRath. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but you should rephrase the question. Do not ask about cursor position, when you need to know how to use `substring`.

Comment: No I wanted to know about retaining cursor position because instead of adding the text at the end I wanted to add it at some specified position. I didn't mention about retaining the "selection", my question was specific to "cursor position".

Comment: hi @phusick I have tried things but I am unable to get it working on IE. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the answer by phusick to suite your needs.

But once you know about the cusron selection on the widget, there is really nothing much to be done here.

**HTML:**

```
<input
    id="textBox1"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
    value="some text here"/>

<button id="button1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">foo</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
    ready,
    registry
) {

    ready(function() {

        var textBox = registry.byId("textBox1"),
            button = registry.byId("button1");        

        textBox.on("blur", function() {
            var start = this.textbox.selectionStart,
                end = this.textbox.selectionEnd;
            this.curStart = start;
            this.curEnd = end;
        });

        textBox.on("focus", function() {
            var cursorPosition = [this.curStart,this.curEnd];
            if(cursorPosition) {            
                this.textbox.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition[1], cursorPosition[1]);                                          
            }
        });

        button.on("click", function() {
            var cur = [textBox.curStart,textBox.curEnd];
         var val = textBox.get("value");
            var str = val.substring(0,cur[0])+ 'foo' + val.substring(cur[1]);
            textBox.set("value", str);
            textBox.focus();
            textBox.textbox.setSelectionRange(cur[0]+'foo'.length, cur[0]+'foo'.length);
        });


    });


});
```

Here is the Fiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/NE4Ev/6/